# Python discord.py/Image : How to edit the ctx.author profile picture with Image and sand it back on discord?

Tags: python, image, request, discord.py

Hey I try to get the avatar picture on discord, then add a text on it and finally send it back in the tchat.

So I tried this to get the image of the user :

- step 1 : get user avatar url
- step 2 : get change url to get correct sized picture
- step 3 : request the image
- step 4 : open the image with Image.open

This is the code I did do these steps :

```py
@bot.command(name="pic")
async def get_pic(ctx):
  url = f"{str(ctx.author.avatar_url)[:-4]}128" # get url and change 1024 to 128
  avatar = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
```

Unfortunately I get an Error 403 : Forbidden.
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: What's the full traceback of the error message?

Comment: You can find you traceback here,https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/690164586489315436/703306287143714962/IMG_20200424_191653.png

Comment: Can you share a sample URL this is happening for?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/459341388656672779/087c7c22eb70be71ae5d5925c961ccbb.png?size=128

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`User.avatar_url_as`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.avatar_url_as) to get the [`Asset` object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Asset) representing the avatar in the desired size, read that data into a file-like object, then open that file-like object with PIL

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

@bot.command(name="pic")
async def get_pic(ctx):
    asset = ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    image = Image.open(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well it describe like this

> The HTTP response code 403 mean access to the requested resource is forbidden. The server understood the request, but will not fulfill it.

Mean that the server get your request but you don't have permission I guess

Happy coding!